# Screen Tip (Title) of People Picker control is not changing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a InfoPath form with a number of fields.
Every field is showing some description (a tooltip) when user hovers over it.

For example, for Age field Screen tip is set to `How old are you?`

[image]

For People Picker, it is set to `Enter you name..`. But it is showing the following, `People Picker`

[image]

Steps I followed:

1. Right Click on the field and select `Properties`
2. Go to `Advanced` tab and enter text in `Screen tip`

Answer (score -2):

```
 $(".ms-inputuserfield").attr("title","customized tooltip")
```

Comment: Elaborate your answer please.

Comment: This is Infopath form. We cannot apply css classes here.